# Display multiple file type in android such as pdf, docx, pptx in android from url

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

On my project i need to display multiple file types such as pdf, docx, pptx from a url in android is it possible to create preview on my application. i spend lot of time for this no result yet.

Comment: `it possible to create preview on my application`. Nice. Then you are nearly done.

Comment: `Please help me.`. Dont ask for help. We expect you to write down your questions instead.

Comment: @greenapps Read the question clearly